# Twine disabling style characters not working when using Harlowe format

Tags: twine

[According to the Twine documentation](http://twinery.org/wiki/twine2:how_to_format_text), if a word has asterisks around it, it's rendered in italics:

*Italics* = *Italics*

If I want to literaly show the asterisks, then I need to put some extra characters around it:

*Boom!*   == ``*Boom!*``

What is <kbd>`</kbd> ?

Is it <kbd>'</kbd>? Because I don't get the desired results when writing ' '*Boom!*' ' or "*Boom!*".

In fact, ''text'' seems to be equivalent to **text** even though it doesn't say that on the doc pages the program links me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>`</kbd> is the backtick character. On a standard QWERTY keyboard, you can find it to the left of the row of number keys, just under the tilde (~):

[image: Image of a keyboard, indicating where to find the backtick key]

> In fact, ''text'' seems to be equivalent to **text** even though it doesn't say that on the doc pages the program links me to.

Sure it does, right in the very first cell of the table explaining Harlowe formatting:

> **Bold**  = **Bold** or ''Bold''

You can select the text to verify that the two ticks on each side of Bold are separate apostrophe characters, not a single double-quotation mark.